# Bootstrap datepicker won't insert null if input is blank

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

This has been asked before and I've read answers that are years old. Is there a fix for this though that doesn't require me to check the input value before inserting into my db?  I was wondering if there's a setting that will allow me to simply have the value = NULL by default when no date is selected.

I am using Bootstrap datepicker.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If an input is left blank, I want to insert NULL into my db.  Right now it inserts 0000-00-00.  My date field is set to be NULL by default.  Something is up with the plugin I'm guessing, or maybe there's a setting I'm missing.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery Date</label>
          <div class="input-icon right">
        <i class="fa"></i>
        <input type="text" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" class="datepicker form-control">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
autoclose: true,
todayBtn: true
});
```

I am using ajax to serialize my forms and then pass the fields to an insert.php script that I have.   The insert.php works for many other forms that I've created for my site.

Comment: do you have a fiddle to test the scenario ?

Comment: No, I don't.   I have been thinking about this though.... I think it's not an issue with the plugin.  I need to eliminate the date fields that are empty before jquery .serialize is called!  I am trying to figure out how to do that.  I bet that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what it was.  I eliminate the empty inputs before serializing and NULL is inserted.

```
$("#myForm :input[value!='']").serialize() // does the job!
```